# Display an image on a Windows.Form from a SQL Database in VB (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have some headshots in an ID Card database that I want to display in a program I am writing in VB 2008. The following code is based off of a support article from Microsoft, it can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321900) and is specifically from step '11'.

```
    aiuQuery.CommandText = "select a.ImageData From Images a, Cardholders b WHERE b.UserText6 = '" & _
                           empID & "' And a.CardholderID = b.CardholderID"
    aiuReader = aiuQuery.ExecuteReader
    If aiuReader.Read Then
        Dim bytBLOBData(aiuReader.GetBytes(1, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
        aiuReader.GetBytes(1, 0, bytBLOBData, 0, bytBLOBData.Length)
        Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
        pbHeadShot.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
    End If
    aiuReader.Close()
```

The first line inside the 'If' block (Dim bytBLOBData...) generates an error claiming "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

The SQL is correct as tested outside of the program.

Any suggestions on what the cause of this error could be? A better way to go about this?

Comment: What does this have to do with vb6?

Comment: I guess that was an error, tag removed, title changed.

Comment: Added the correct tag for the Language used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) requires, as first parameter, the index of the field to read.
In NET the array indexes start at zero not at 1

```
  Dim bytBLOBData(aiuReader.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
  aiuReader.GetBytes(0, 0, bytBLOBData, 0, bytBLOBData.Length)
```

You query returns just one field and thus you should use the value 0 for the first parameter